# BusProvider Not Returning to @Subscribe

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-asynctask, otto

I am using BusProvider with on Android to handle post backs to the main thread after executing an AsynTask. When the Async task is finished and it is successful it registers the Post and returns to the MAIN thread to display an alert dialog. When it fails though, i would like it to return to the same method in the MAIN thread and display a message as to why it failed. In this case it is signing up, so it could be as simple as "This  email is already being used".

This doesnt seem to be working for me and it never makes it back to the MAIN thread.

In my Async task using the BusProvider, i am posting back this on failure:

```
 @Override
        public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
            BusProvider.getInstance().post(new SignupTask.ErrorEvent(new String(((TypedByteArray) error.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes())));
        }
```

It is then passed into the class ErrorEvent:

```
public class ErrorEvent {

    public String message;

    public ErrorEvent(String message) {
        this.message = ResponseParser(message);
    }

    public String ResponseParser(String response){
        //Handle JSON parsing here of response, need message + the array stack to display to the user what is exactly wrong
        return response;
    }

}
```

Still some work to be done there but before i parse the info i would like to just pass the response back for now.

The response is NOT null and i have checked this while debugging. Once it gets back to the BusProvider.getInstance().post(...) it never returns to the MAIN thread and hit my @Subscribe

@Subscribe:

```
@Subscribe
public void onSignUpSuccess(SignupResponse event) {
    loading.dismiss();

    if(!BuildConfig.DEBUG_MODE) {
        Log.i(TAG, "!BuildConfig.DEBUG_MODE : " + AnswersAnalytics.SIGN_UP_PATIENT);
        Answers.getInstance().logCustom(new CustomEvent(AnswersAnalytics.SIGN_UP));
    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignupActivity.this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("Thank you");
    alertDialog.setMessage(event.getMsg());
    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    killSignup();
                }
            });
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

I would like to use this same @Subscribe to handle the error and display it.

Any help is much greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't post event from another thread to UI thread. You could use `Handler` for this.

```
private Handler mHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        synchronized (this) {
            BusProvider.get().post(msg.obj);
        }
    }
};

private void post(Object message) {
    Message msg = mHandler.obtainMessage(0);
    msg.obj = message;
    mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
}

@Override
public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
    this.post(new SignupTask.ErrorEvent(new String(((TypedByteArray) error.getResponse().getBody()).getBytes())));
}
```

Comment: i have tried this and i am still not getting to the parent view to remove the spinner.dismiss(). Its on the main thread in the parent activity from the AsyncTask

Comment: Did you try to debug `Bus`.`post` method? It just calls subscribed method via reflection, no magic is there. Just check how it goes throuht otto classes in methods that are already work in your project and compare them to your current non-working one. it's neither your class is not registered ( or registered from another Bus) neither you call it from another thread. You can also check memory usage during stacking `post` handlers, if your memory goes up it means something is wrong, if it's on same lvl or gets cleared by `GC` you just messed up with registration.

Comment: the current subscribe method works fine when i get a success back from the server, just doesnt work on a failure. It doesnt even make it to the breakpoint i placed in the subscribe method

Comment: You can try step by step moving to success method. I mean if one method works and another one doesn't just find the difference between them. First of all try to post  `SignupTask.Success` instead of `SignupTask.ErrorEvent` in `failure`, check if subscribed success  event  on your activity gets called.  Then try to call `onSignUpSuccess` via `post` from `success`.

Comment: Im confused on what your asking me to try, onSignUpSuccess is called when i do a post in success. I cant change SignupTask.ErrorEvent to Success because it is handling an error from the server...what would changing it to success do?

Comment: I can provide you with more information or if you would like to move to a chat client that could work easier too

Comment: It turned out to be the object i was sending back to the handler did not match to the success method, you were right. It took me a little while to understand what you were trying to say but i am very grateful for your help!

Comment: Glad I could help :)